# How to reset viewports camera angle?

Tags: 3d-view, camera

Strange question maybe but my viewport camera is skewed on a weird angle.
(like 35-45 degrees) wondering how to fix it.

Comment: to completely reset the camera, press Alt+ R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and press <kbd>Numpad 4</kbd> or <kbd>Numpad 6</kbd> until your camera is at the correct angle.

Comment: Thank you, it does rotate it so it helped, but still not perfect, needs another hit of the numpad but with less rotation if that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

you can always go to the default cameras by pressing <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>, <kbd>Numpad 3</kbd>,<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

In the 3D view, press N to show the Properties panel if it's not already showing.

Select the camera object and the Properties panel will show the Location (X, Y & Z) and its Rotation (X, Y & Z).

You can enter any values you want in those fields.

Alternatively, in the same Properties Panel, with the Camera selected, check **Lock Camera To View**.  Now when you change the view, the camera will be updated.  When you're happy with the angle of the camera, uncheck **Lock Camera To View**.  Fine tune it by editing the fields as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Go to *View* and set *Lock* to *3d Cursor*, if your cursor is in center.